# Resource already defined gradle Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have different image sizes in my drawable resource folders for different screen sizes. they are all splash_login.png splash_screen.png. In my layout-large resource directory however I have splash_login.jpg and splash_screen.jpg because the images are very big. Now when I try to run gradle build i get the following error in  my stack trace

```
build/intermediates/symbols/release
Error Code:1
Output:
res/drawable-large-v4/splash_login.png:0: error: Resource entry splash_login is    already defined.
res/drawable-large-v4/splash_login.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
res/drawable-large-v4/splash_screen.png:0: error: Resource entry splash_screen is already defined.
res/drawable-large-v4/splash_screen.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
```

I know this is occuring because the file extention has changed but does anyone know how to get around it without reverting my large images to .png files??

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. Running the following command fixed it for me :

```
 gradle clean build assemble
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally happen when you rename a resource (I had the problem with a `.xml.xml` I had to change to `.xml`)

From Android Studio :

***Build*** > Rebuild Project

Comment: Apparently applies to changing an image format as well. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

another option is to find the file in the build cache folders and rename/delete it there.

on my windows machine the problem file was in the '[project directory]\build\res\all\debug\raw' folder